# Publicly access different ports in one ec2 instances from different domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I successfully run 3 container on one ec2 instances using cluster.
Now the 3 apps can be accessed publicly through the instance's public dns but with different ports.

- App 1 url => https://public-dns-of-the-instance:1010/
- App 2 url => https://public-dns-of-the-instance:1020/
- App 3 url => https://public-dns-of-the-instance:1030/

What I want now is like these:

- https://admin.mydomain.com/ is point to App 1
- https://cs.mydomain.com/ is point to App 2
- https://member.mydomain.com/ is point to App 3

Comment: You can't do that without a load balancer or some other proxy.

Comment: Any suggested documentation? Have tried using lb, but somehow cant set the target

Comment: Can be acchieved with Application Load Balancer. Create a new target group for each of the application and specify the corresponding port number. Then use the Loadbalancer rules to forward domain based requests to appropriate target group. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-target-group.html. Also just a thought if you are running containers better use ECS these things would come out of the box.